# Issue in publishing swagger doc for google cloud endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, swagger-ui, gcloud, openapi

I am trying to publish Swagger documentation for my cloud endpoints. My application is in Python. As per the documentation [1]:

1.) I downloaded the repository from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui.git.

2.) Copied the dist directory from the downloaded repository and placed into the docs folder inside my project. I created a new folder with name docs.

3,) As per the step 3, the project name should be FQDN. The project name I have in openapi.yaml is-> host: "sample-project-******.appspot.com"

4.) As given in step 4 in the documentation, I added following in app.yaml

```
handlers:
  - url: /docs
    static_files: docs/index.html
    upload: docs/index.html
  - url: /docs/(.*)
    static_files: docs/\1
    upload: docs/.
```

5.) Updated the URL entry in docs/index.html with the following:

```
url = "../api-docs";
```

6.) Added following in openapi.yaml

```
"/docs":
    get:
      description: "Documentation"
      operationId: "docs"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Documentation"
```

Questions:

- What is the significance of adding *url = "../api-docs"* in step 5?
- When I am hitting /docs, I am getting 404.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/adding-swagger

Comment: For the 404 issue, after you modified the openapi.yaml, did you do "gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi.yaml", and then update the configuration ID in app.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

In regards to adding "url", from the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/adding-swagger:

> This directs the Swagger UI to retrieve your OpenApi spec from this URL. Add a handler for this path which reads your openapi.yaml and serves it as json.

Also, for exposing your Swagger documentation, you might want to consider that Endpoints is working on a developer portal feature and looking for users: https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/03/now-you-can-automatically-document-your-API-with-Cloud-Endpoints.html